# Add Comma Separated String to a Table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a comma separated string with which I want to replace the contents of the existing table with.

For e.g. I have this string:

```
var str = "Mike, Andy, Paul";
```

I wish to replace the entire contents of a table (class name - #staff) with this string taking a new row in the table for each new name that the string contains.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#staff').empty();
$.each(str.split(','),function(i,v){
   $('#staff').append("<tr><td>"+$.trim(v)+"</td></tr>");
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/g2UwK/10/

Comment: you forgot to clear the table first